# Editor keyboard shortcuts in Spyder don't work in command window

Tags: python, keyboard-shortcuts, spyder

I am running Spyder 4.0.1 (installed via Anaconda) on Max OS and I have an issue with the keyboard shortcuts.

I customized some of the shortcuts for the editor (e.g. "cmd + ->" for "skip to end of line") and they work nicely in the editor window. But the same shortcuts don't work in the command window (there the shortcut is "fn + ->").

Is there any way to customize the shortcuts for the command window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) The shortcuts in the IPython console are not configurable at the moment, sorry.